# Como pegar item selecionado de um ComboBox em javaFx

Tags: javafx

Como posso pegar o item selecionado de um ComboBox?

Vi algumas formas de fazer mas não consegui implementar, ou seja não entendi como funciona.

Eu consigo setar os items do comboBox da seguinte forma:

```
 ObservableList<String> options
                = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        "Ativo",
                        "Suspenso"

                );
        cbStatus.setItems(options);
```

só falta conseguir pega-los quando eu seleciona-los no comboBox.

Comment: A tua pergunta está incompleta... o "já tentei algumas coisas" ou dizer "o javaFX é mais chato que o swing" não ajuda muito... BTW  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/SetandgetvalueforComboBox.htm ou este http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JavaFX/0590__JavaFX_ComboBox.htm a ver se ajuda...

Comment: Já tentei usar o getValue porém não funcionou

Comment: Problema resolvido, criei um evento de MouseCliked e consigo pegar o valor dentro desse evento. Obrigado

Comment: Muito melhor agora a sua pergunta, o meu +1... E ainda bem que consegui.

Answer (score 1):

Dependendo se quiser usar a propriedade ou o valor diretamente é diferente.

```
//por valor
cbStatus.getValue();
cbStatus.valueProperty().get();

//bind com a propriedade
statusProperty.bind(cbStatus.valueProperty());
```